# Laptop webcam no longer recognised after system upgrade

Tags: laptop, 15.04, webcam, camera

As the title implies, my laptop no longer seems to see the built in webcam. I installed 15.04 about a week ago and it's been fine until around yesterday.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 1770:ff00  
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 8: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
```

`ls /dev/video*`:

```
ls: cannot access `/dev/video*`: No such file or directory
```

As always, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try different webcam software first. A few options: guvcview and "Cheese". sudo apt-get install guvcview cheese Do you get any image? What did you change to your computer?

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `lsusb` and `ls/dev/video*`

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb -t` & `lsusb`?

Comment: I've updated with all the said commands.

Comment: it should be `ls /dev/video*` (above comment is missing a space). I had this issue a couple of days ago and a reboot fixed it.

Comment: Tried it with the space, no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with 14.04 until I installed "Cheese Webcam Booth" and then it worked fine.

Comment: Cheese just tells me that there is no webcam found.